# Sourcing files in shell script vs sourcing on command line

Tags: linux, bash, shell, environment

I have the problem that my shell script is not acting exactly the same as my manual typing into a console. I am attempting to find and source some setup files in a shell script as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

TURTLE_SHELL=bash

# source setup.sh from same directory as this file
_TURTLE_SETUP_DIR=$(builtin cd "`dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"`" > /dev/null && pwd)
. "$_TURTLE_SETUP_DIR/turtle_setup.sh"
```

This bash file calls a .sh file:

```
#!/bin/env sh
_TURTLE_ROS_SETUP_DIR=$_TURTLE_SETUP_DIR/../devel

if [ -z "$TURTLE_SHELL" ]; then
  TURTLE_SHELL=sh
fi

if [ -d "$PX4_FIRMWARE_DIR/integrationtests" ]; then
  if [ -f "$PX4_FIRMWARE_DIR/integrationtests/setup_gazebo_ros.bash" ]; then
    . "$PX4_FIRMWARE_DIR/integrationtests/setup_gazebo_ros.bash" "$PX4_FIRMWARE_DIR" 
  fi
fi

if [ "$TURTLE_SHELL" = "bash" ]; then
  if [ -f "$_TURTLE_ROS_SETUP_DIR/setup.bash" ]; then
    source $_TURTLE_ROS_SETUP_DIR/setup.bash
  fi
else
  if [ "$TURTLE_SHELL" = "sh" ]; then
    if [ -f "$_TURTLE_ROS_SETUP_DIR/setup.sh" ]; then
      source $_TURTLE_ROS_SETUP_DIR/setup.sh
    fi
  fi
fi
```

The line in question is:

```
. "$PX4_FIRMWARE_DIR/integrationtests/setup_gazebo_ros.bash" "$PX4_FIRMWARE_DIR"
```

I have made sure that this code is actually running and that my environment variables are correct. If I run this command on the command line everything works well. However, the same is not true when the file is sourced via shell script. Why is this? Is there something different about the environment of a shell script that is different from a command line. Also, how can I fix this problem?

Edit:
I am **sourcing** either the .bash or the .sh scale, depending upon which shell I am using.

Edit 2:
I am **sourcing** this script. Thus, everything is run in my default bash terminal, and it is all run within the same terminal and **not** a terminal spawned from a child process. Why is the script not sourcing setup_gazebo_ros.bash within the current shell?

Comment: What is the problem, exactly? All you say is that the behaviour is different. How does it differ? By the way, when you source a file, elther with the `.` or `source` command, it runs in the same shell. So you can't "call a .sh script" from bash with a `.` command, nor will you be able to use bash extensions in a `.bash` file sourced from a script running in /bin/sh. It's pointless to put a `#!` line in a file which will be sourced, and it is usually a bad idea to include the comment (which is what the line becomes), because it is misleading.

Comment: You're also mixing up `sh` and `bash` - they are *not* the same thing.

Comment: @rici Can I source a .bash file in a .sh file from a bash terminal? This behavior is working fine for the call to source the second script in the second file, $_TURTLE_ROS_SETUP_DIR/setup.bash . The logic behind this is that if this behavior is valid, then if I call the correct wrapper script, the correct $_TURTLE_ROS_SETUP scripts will always be called.

Comment: The test for directory and then file within directory is not really necessary.  If the directory doesn't exist, the test for the file within it won't work.  Since you only read the file, you may as well drop the directory check and simply test for the existence of the file.

Comment: If the contents of the sourced file are compatible with (understood by) the shell doing the sourcing, there's no problem with the shebang lines. (Why mix up dotting and sourcing? The operation's the same, but `.` is understood by all POSIX shells, but only shells that have been corrupted by the C shell understand `source`.)  If you write in the portable (POSIX) subset of the shell, there'll be no issues.  If you use features specific to Bash, you may run into problems.

Comment: @errolflynn: "calling" and "sourcing" are different operations. If you use the words as though they were synonyms, you just create confusion. When you source a file (normally using the `.` command), the shebang line and the file extension are irrelevant; the file is interpreted by whatever shell executed the `.` command. When you explicitly use a specific shell to call a script (eg. `sh foo.bash`)`, the shebang and extension are also irrelevant. The shebang is only used if you execute the script directly (eg. `./foo.bash`).

Comment: I am sourcing this script. Thus, everything is run in my default bash terminal, and it is all run within the same terminal. Why is the script not sourcing setup_gazebo_ros.bash within the current shell?

Comment: This code makes no sense. You're using the `source` keyword if the shell is `sh` -- but `sh` doesn't recognize `source`, it only recognizes `.`. Why are you trying to put a conditional in place rather than always using `.` (which is mandated by POSIX and universally available) anyhow?

Comment: ...anyhow, surely you can generate a minimal reproducer with less silly boilerplate that anyone (including people who don't have `setup_gazebo_ros.bash`) can run. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve -- code samples included in StackOverflow questions should be **minimal** (including nothing more than the minimum needed to reproduce the problem), **complete** and **verifiable** (allowing anyone else to copy-and-paste and reproduce the issue). As asked, this doesn't meet that spec.

Answer (score 2):

It's the same reason why you source the env script and not run it.  When you run the script it runs in a new shell and the variables are not transferred back to the parent shell.

To illustrate

```
$ cat << ! > foo.sh
> export foo='FOO'
> !

$ chmod +x foo.sh 
$ ./foo.sh
$ echo $foo

$ source ./foo.sh
$ echo $foo
FOO
```

Comment: Is there a way to get around this?